# Area of greatest integer function

Tags: integration, area

**Question:**

> Find the area enclosed by the function:
>   $$\left\lfloor\frac{\left|3x + 4y\right|}{5}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{\left|4x - 3y\right|}{5}\right\rfloor = 3$$
>   where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ represents the greatest-integer function.

I believe the easiest way to solve this problem would be to graph the function. However, I was unable to do so. Please note that this was a question on an examination and there was no graphing equipment available.

Comment: I think it represents diagonals of a rhombus

Comment: Oh so the inner ones are absolute value? I was wondering what is wrong...

Comment: Why did you write "Where" with a capital "W" as if it were the beginning of a sentence, rather than just continuing the sentence already underway?  I see that a lot on stackexchange.  Someone suggested it's because of some editing software that comes with Microsoft Windows, but I'm not convinced that that is true or can explain it. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry. Habit of capitalizing the first letter of the line whenever I press enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can separate it into cases :
$$\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=3$$
$$\iff \left(\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor\right)=(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0)$$

Now note that 
$$\left\lfloor Z\right\rfloor=a\iff a\le Z\lt a+1$$
and that $\frac{|3X+4Y|}{5},\frac{|4X-3Y|}{5}$ represents the distance between a point $(X,Y)$ and the line $3x+4y=0, 4x-3y=0$ respectively.

Since the two lines intersect perpendicularly, we have $16$ unit squares, and so the answer is $\color{red}{16}$.

Comment: AHA! Eureka moment. I did the first step (i.e. separating into cases). then... I got confused and I didn't get the idea of the line thing.
But wait.... Yes the lines intersect. What does the case thing have to do with that? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Gummybears: Let us consider the first case $\lfloor|3x+4y|/5\rfloor=0,\lfloor |4x-3y|/5\rfloor=3$. This is equivalent to $0\le|3x+4y|/5\lt 1$ and $3\le |4x-3y|/5\lt 4$. Note here again that $|3x+4y|/5,|4x-3y|/5$ represents the distance between a point $(x,y)$ and the line $3x+4y=0, 4x-3y=0$ respectively. You'll get 4 unit squares in this case when you draw lines paralell either to $3x+4y=0$ or $4x-3y=0$. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(%7C3x%2B4y%7C%2F5)%2Bfloor(%7C4x-3y%7C%2F5)%3D3) should help.

Comment: Okay. So essentially for one of the cases, we get a square of 4 unit area. Then we repeat the cases to get 4 squares of the same area, i.e the total area is 16 units. Right?

Comment: @Gummybears: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Good to know that at least I was on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you remember that there is a right triangle with sides $3$, $4$, $5$. This then implies that
$$u:={4\over5}x-{3\over5}y,\qquad v:={3\over5}x+{4\over5}y$$
are orthonormal coordinates in the plane (see the figure). In terms of these coordinates the given equation reads
$$\bigl\lfloor |v|\bigr\rfloor+\bigl\lfloor |u|\bigr\rfloor=3\ .\tag{1}$$
Draw an $(u,v)$-plane with horizontal $u$-axis and vertical $v$-axis. Because of the absolute value signs the set $S$ of points $(u,v)$ satisfying $(1)$ is symmetric with respect to both axes. Therefore it is sufficient to determine the part of $S$ lying in the first quadrant.

Now stare at the figure and find out which points in the first quadrant of the $(u,v)$-plane satisfy $\lfloor u\rfloor+\lfloor v\rfloor =3$.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain a couple of things:
What are orthonormal coordinates?
And yes, the right triangle thing I know. But... What happened after that? Completely lost..